# Plotting multiple barplots against months using Base R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, data-visualization

I need help plotting temperature data for each day of the year. I have the data in a dataset of the following form:

`weather(month, day, low, high, recordLow, recordHigh)`

```
m d l  h  rl rh
1 1 44 60 35 72
1 2 32 63 31 76
...
```

`month` goes from 1 to 12, and `day` goes from 1 to whatever the last day of the particular month is.

For each day (on the X axis), I want two bars, overlayed on each other, one extending from `low` to `high` and the other extending from `recordLow` to `recordHigh`. I don't know what function of Base R to use (No ggplot) and how to use it. I want them all to be drawn in the same graph with the same axes.

Comment: extending from low to high means?

Comment: why not ggplot? is this some sort of assignment that you want to get done from us :p

Comment: @joel.wilson I want a thin bar for each day that starts at the 'low' value for the day and streches all the way to the 'high'. Like the graphs here: http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=00014g

Comment: @joel.wilson Yes this IS homework, with the additional explanation that I have been spending three days on this part, that what I gave you is not the whole question or the exact dataset, that I have been Googling for two days without any fruit, and that the professor/TAs aren't helping/can't help. Also, we haven't been told not to use ggplot, but I only have a few more days left and feel like it will take too much time to learn it than I can afford.

Comment: hey...with barplots the base has to be fixed right.. and you want it to vary based on (l,rl) That is not possible. what you are asking for is like floating bars.